# Spring WebFlux - Retrying Mono from the middle of the flow

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Suppose, we have the following code:

```
T someObject = ...;
return step1(someObject)
            .flatMap(this::step2)
            .flatMap(this::step3)
            .flatMap(this::step4)
            .flatMap(this::step5)
            .timeout(timeout)
            .retryBackoff(numberOfRetries, Duration.ofMillis(100));
```

Each one of those step methods returns a new Mono

At the moment with this implementation, if an exception occurs in step3, step4 or step5, the whole flow is repeated starting from step2.  I would like to be able to restart the flow from where the exception occured, e.g. if an exception happened in step4, flow is repeated only from step4 (of course, the input repeated is the successful response from step3).

Is that possible to implement in some way in the current version??

#### Reactor Core version

3.2.2.RELEASE

#### JVM version (e.g. `java -version`)

1.8

Answer (score 3):

You could apply individual `retryBackoff` for each step.

```
T someObject = ...;
return step1(someObject)
        .flatMap(o1 -> step2(o1).retryBackoff(...))
        .flatMap(o2 -> step3(o2).retryBackoff(...))
```

It would be better to incapsulate individual timeots and retryBackOffs into `stepN` methods